# How can I compare a ClassDeclarationSyntax object against an IdentifierNameSyntax object?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, sourcegenerators

I'm writing a source generator in C#, and I've got 2 objects that I need to compare to see if they relate to the same class, but I can't find a way to do it.

My first object is an instance of `ClassDeclarationSyntax`.  This is coming from my custom `ISyntaxContextReceiver` to find classes that match specific conditions.

Elsewhere in my generator I have an `IdentifierNameSyntax` object, which is coming from looking at the types within a `TypeOfExpressionSyntax` that I find within a different class's list of attributes.

I need to compare the two objects here to see if they are talking about the same thing.

With the `IdentifierNameSyntax` I can get the type information by using the semantic model:

```cs
ITypeSymbol semanticType = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(targetType).Type;
```

But I don't know how to compare this `ITypeSymbol` against `ClassDeclarationSyntax` either.

Is there a way to do this, or is there a way to get the semantic model type information for a `ClassDeclarationSyntax` object?

Comment: I think you're looking for `semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration)`, no?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.  Thank you @KirkWoll - if you want to pop this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Cool, glad that helped.  I've provided an answer so you can close the loop on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `GetDeclaredSymbol` on `semanticModel`.  As [you can see from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpextensions.getdeclaredsymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.2.0), there are huge number of overloads which will allow you to get the associated symbol information for not only classes, but also fields, methods, properties, events, parameters, and so forth.  Definitely a method you'll want to keep in your back pocket!